# Uncaught Type Error when trying to scroll Ext.List

Tags: list, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I'm experimenting with Sencha Touch 2 at the moment. I made a simple json-store with more items than my screen can display to test scrolling, but every time i try to scroll i get following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'getCount' of null
```

I tried to find out whats wrong but could not find a solution yet. Maybe anyone can help?
Here are my sample files:

host.json:

```
{
"hosts": [
    {
        "host_name": "host 1",
        "status": "pending"
    },
    {
        "host_name": "host 2",
        "status": "normal"
    },
    {
        "host_name": "host 3",
        "status": "critical"
    }

            ...

]
}
```

My Store:

```
Ext.define('myapp.store.MyStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

config: {
    storeId: 'mystore',
    model: 'myapp.model.MyModel',

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'host.json',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            rootProperty: 'hosts'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
}

});
```

The List-View:

```
  Ext.define('myapp.view.MyListView', {
extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
alias: 'widget.mylistview',



config: {
    items: {
        xtype: 'list',
        store: 'mystore',
        itemTpl: '<div class="service_status_{status}">{host_name}</div>'
    }
}
});
```

And the view where the List-View is called:

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.Container',

config: {
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        aligh: 'stretch'
    },

    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'mytoolbar',
            docked: 'top',
            height: 50
        },
        {
            xtype: 'mylistview',
            flex: 1
        }
    ]
}
});
```

Comment: Found the solution: You have to use a 'fit'-layout for the listview. I changed the listview to be container with fit-layout, now it scrolls flawlessly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 'fit' layout might solve it.

**Here is something you definately should change too:**

This already defines a list

```
Ext.define('myapp.view.MyListView', {
    extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
    xtype: 'mylistview',
```

This is the config of the list:

```
    config: {
```

Here you add a list inside the list, which you are actually using.
This will not go well. This would be a good reason something is not working as expected.

```
    items: {
        xtype: 'list',
        store: 'mystore',
        itemTpl: '<div class="service_status_{status}">{host_name}</div>'
    }
```